Which Endpoint should I use for Chimera for Security Review
Here is a similar question Question about Endpoint scanning (ZAP) for security review
But I can't get the precise answer.
As the answer showed , I should use the particular endpoint, like "https://xxx.com/a/b".
Our situation is the endpoint is used for callout with http method POST and some encryption method. You can't visit the endpoint just in the browser.

So will the scan succeed while you can't visit this endpoint from browser?
We have multiple callouts. Do we have to start a new scan for each one? Or just scan the root domain ?

such as:
https://xxx.com/a/b
https://xxx.com/a/c
https://xxx.com/a/d
or
https://xxx.com
Which url should I use for the Chimera scan for Security Review?
Thanks for the help.
